# Closed form for $\sum _{k=1} ^n \frac k 2 \,\operatorname{sgn} \left( \frac 1 {k^2} + \cos \frac {2\pi n} k-1 \right)$

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, closed-form-expressions

I am looking for the closed form of
$$\sum _{k=1} ^n \frac k 2 \,\operatorname{sgn} \left( \frac 1 {k^2} + \cos \frac {2\pi n} k-1 \right) \ .$$
Wolfram Alpha cannot do this for me, so I am forced to ask Stack Exchange for an answer.

Comment: $\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac1{k^2}+\cos\frac{2\pi n}k-1\right)$ is $1$ if $k$ is a divisor of $n$ and $-1$ if not. Hence your sum is $\sigma(n)-\frac{n(n+1)}4$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$.